# Iterating through a list and adding to db context

Tags: c#, entity

I am trying to add insert data into a DB using Entity Framework.

`public class list1 {
    public string element1 { get; set; }
    public string element2 { get; set; }
    public string element3 { get; set; }
    public string element4 { get; set; }
    public string element5 { get; set; }
}`

The above list contains the populated fields but is at the business layer.

`public class list2 {
    public string element1 { get; set; }
    public string element2 { get; set; }
    public string element3 { get; set; }
    public string element4 { get; set; }
    public string element5 { get; set; }
}`

The above list is the Entity Framework object that maps to the DB how can I iterate through copying the data across between them?

> var foo = ConvertJson.Convert<"list1">(strResponseJSONContent);  using (var db = new DBContext())
>       {
>           foreach (var element in foo)
>           {
>               db.list2.Add(element);
>           }
>       }

I am getting the error at this line `db.list2.Add(element);` that says 'The best overloaded method contains some invalid arguments'. I am not sure as to why this error is being generated.
I thought using a foreach loop and adding them to the context would work but it isn't. 
Any suggestions? Do i need to map them first or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You must call `db.SaveChanges()` to commit your changes...

More importantly, you need to have a class that extends `DBContext` that models your database and not instantiate `DbContext` directly.

Also the `Add` method adds elements to a `Collection` not to a class with `Add` method. The `DbContext` you extend must have a `DbSet` member. I recommend you try a Entity Frameowrk tutorial like this one:
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear I have updated the question to try and convey my question better. The error is not with the `SaveChanges` line.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have given the type name as `list2` the type is not a `List`, it is a class. So you will not have a method named `Add` to it. You probably need a `List<list2>` but not sure as it depends on your business requirement.